# Navigation controller with two views

Tags: ios

I have a navigation controller that controls view switch. How can I show a view without removing the current view?

Answer (score 0):

if your new view has a view controller use

[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:newController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

This will add a view to the viewcontrollers view.

```
[parentView addSubview:subView];
```

This will add the view in variable `subView` into the view in variable `parentView`. In your case this would mean parentView is the viewcontroller's view and the subView is the view you want to add.

You can change the position of the subView in the parentView by setting the subview's subview.frame property.

If you are talking about a viewController you want to show take a look at the answer of Andiih.